# Mass-update with batch file in Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory

We have to update several workstations in network regularly. We have batch file that admnistrators run on workstations when updates are ready (updates are files in shared folder in network)

Administrators told me to prepare msi file to perform the same task with Active Directory. May I tell administrators to use exactly the same batch file they ran manually, not msi as they expect? May batch files be used in Active Directory for mass client workstations update?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the admins are planning on pushing out an update by assigning it in group policy hence the need for an msi. See [HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783635%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for more information. Since group policy will now take care of making sure the software is installed your script will not be needed.

[Here is a StackOverflow post on creating a .msi from exe's.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854873/how-to-make-msi-that-simply-wraps-exe)

Ensure if your program has any custom install options you also look at creating a Microsoft Transform File (.mst) to go along with your Microsoft Installer File(.msi). The transform file will automatically choose all the install options you deem necessary.